# Podfiles seem to be causing issues with building in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, project, podfile

I am currently working on a project within `Xcode` using `Cocoapods` as a plugin which include some plugins like the `GoogleMessagingService`. However, I get this one error everytime I compile this project and it will only go away when I remove `Cocoapods` from my project.

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/matponting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-----bpdgcivsmcggtlcgfgywekonicxg/Build/Intermediates/----.build/Debug-iphoneos/----.build/Script-5DA7142BEDB6A002149910F5.sh
cd /Users/matponting/Desktop/OriginalCordova/-----Ionic/platforms/ios
/bin/sh -c /Users/matponting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-----bpdgcivsmcggtlcgfgywekonicxg/Build/Intermediates/----.build/Debug-iphoneos/----.build/Script-5DA7142BEDB6A002149910F5.sh
```

NOTE: I have withheld some naming here for confidentality reasons so some '----' is the name.

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

These errors occur only when `Cocoapods` is used within the project and when removed it will be fine with different results that can be solved but I do need `Cocoapods` to make the thing I am currently working with work.

Now, I have researched into this information and have come across multiple fixes such as cleaning the project and recompiling, using different version of `Cocoapods`. However, I have tried these and I still got the same error.

Is there something I am missing??

EDIT: I have tried also using 'pod update' but have had no success.

Comment: If you are using macOS high Sierra then you need to update cocoa pod "pod update".

Comment: I get the same error when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your project missing Podfile.lock file and pods folder.

so delete your workspace and try installing pod again.

[image]

Comment: I did that and got it stuck me back where I started. I have solved the issue and hopefully will respond when I have a bit of time on my hands.

Comment: @mathew, it would be nice to see how you solved this.